# Blurry image due to sun-damaged backup camera

Tags: mazda, backup-camera, cx9

I have a 2013 Mazda CX-9. I have blurry image on the NAV display. The backup camera's outer lens seems to be sun damaged. Its surface is not smooth and it is not shiny. Is there an easy fix for this tiny lens?

Comment: The outer clear part actually shouldn't be the lense. That's is most likely just the clear covering something akin to how a headlight works. If the outer surface is damaged, you should be able to polish it to get it clear again. Not for sure on this, so leaving it as a comment. Try at your own risk.